# How do you print a full array of values in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to figure out print a full array in C++.
For example, I want the output to be x = [1,2,3,4,5....n]
How would I go about doing this? I already know how to print each element of the array using a simple for loop. For example in python, you could simply say x = [], make a for loop to append elements to the array, and print x.

So let's say I have this code.

```
int n = 10;
int m = 10;
double x[n];

// Generate vector of random values for x
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
{
    x[i] = (double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    // Print each array element
    // std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;

}

std::cout << x[n-1] << std::endl;
```

This obviously only spits out x[10] in this case. Where as I want x = [1...n] etc.
What is the simplest way of achieving this?

I'm using Eclipse on OSX. I use the g++ compiler that the Xcode developer tools has for the command line

Comment: `std::cout << x[n] << std::endl;` accesses the array out of bounds, did you realize that?

Comment: Yep, I did, sorry about that. I meant x[n-1]

Comment: What's the problem with the line that you have commented out? Doesn't it do exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: Well, it prints out each iteration line by line. In python when you append elements to an array, and print x, the output is 'x = [1, 2,...n]'. Python is the main language I learned in, so I might be thinking about this in the wrong way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a [range based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
double x[] = { .0, .1, .2, .3, .4 };
// Iterate through all elements
for (auto d : x)
{
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the above takes a *copy* of each element, so if you wanted to modify an element you'd need to use

```
for (auto& d : x)
```

instead.

Alternatively you could just use a normal `for` loop like you did originally:

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
{
    std::cout << x[i] << std::endl;
}
```

The range based `for` loop is the *easiest* though.

Comment: Is there a module I need to import for a range based for loop? I'm getting the error "warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension" (I'm pretty new to c++, so I've never heard of range based for loops)

Comment: You may not have C++11, or you may be compiling without C++11 extensions. What IDE are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse on OSX. I use the g++ compiler that the Xcode developer tools has for the command line

Comment: Ah, you are officially out of my domain. You can try adding this information to your question or better spend your time trying to enable c++11 extensions in your IDE

Answer (score 2):

if you know something about STL , you can try to use iterator

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
   copy(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int),ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```